# Implementation of container searchable by any element

Tags: c++, graph, template, c++17, binary-search

Writing game engine as a hobby, I've come across many situations where I need a container like a map, but searchable by different keys: a block allocator where a block needs to be searched by either offset or size, or resources searchable by either name or file.

Having multiple maps for each of those keys is ugly and pain in the ass to erase an entry, so I came up with the following.

### Implementation:

```
template <typename... T>
class omni_map
{
    static constexpr size_t num_element = sizeof...(T);

    using tuple_t = std::tuple<T...>;

    template <size_t I>
    using element_t = typename std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple_t>;

    struct node;

    struct branch {
        branch() : 
            left(nullptr), 
            right(nullptr) {}
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    struct node {
        node(T&&... t) :
            values(t...) {}
        tuple_t values;
        branch branches[num_element];
    };

public:
    template <size_t I>
    class iterator {
        friend class omni_map<T...>;
    public:
        iterator(node* n = nullptr) :
            curr(n) {}
        const tuple_t& operator*() {
            return curr->values;
        }
        const tuple_t& operator->() {
            return curr->values;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator<I>& r) {
            return curr == r.curr;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator<I>& r) {
            return curr != r.curr;
        }
    private:
        node* curr;
    };

public:
    omni_map() : 
        m_roots{ nullptr } {}

    void emplace(T&&... t) {
        node* n = m_nodepool.construct(std::forward<T>(t)...);
        insert_node<0>(n);
    }

    template <size_t I>
    iterator<I> find(const element_t<I>& value) {
        node* curr = m_roots[I];
        while (curr)
            if (value < std::get<I>(curr->values))
                curr = curr->branches[I].left;
            else if (value > std::get<I>(curr->values))
                curr = curr->branches[I].right;
            else
                return iterator<I>(curr);
        return iterator<I>();
    }

    template <size_t I>
    void erase(iterator<I> it) {
        remove_node<0>(it.curr);
        m_nodepool.destroy(it.curr);
    }

    template <size_t I>
    iterator<I> begin() {
        node* curr = m_roots[I];
        while (curr->branches[I].left)
            curr = curr->branches[I].left;
        return iterator<I>(curr);
    }

    template <size_t I>
    iterator<I> end() {
        return iterator<I>();
    }

private:
    template <size_t I>
    void insert_node(node* n) {
        node** curr = &m_roots[I];
        while (*curr) {
            if (std::get<I>(n->values) <= std::get<I>((*curr)->values))
                curr = &(*curr)->branches[I].left;
            else
                curr = &(*curr)->branches[I].right;
        }
        *curr = n;
        insert_node<I + 1>(n);
    }

    template <>
    void insert_node<num_element>(node* n) {}

    template <size_t I>
    void remove_node(node* n) {
        node** curr = &m_roots[I];
        while (*curr != n)
            if (std::get<I>(n->values) <= std::get<I>((*curr)->values))
                curr = &(*curr)->branches[I].left;
            else
                curr = &(*curr)->branches[I].right;
        if (n->branches[I].left)
            if (n->branches[I].right) {
                node* left = n->branches[I].left;
                node* max_left = n->branches[I].left;
                while (max_left->branches[I].right)
                    max_left = max_left->branches[I].right;
                *curr = max_left;
                while (max_left->branches[I].left)
                    max_left = max_left->branches[I].left;
                max_left->branches[I].left = left;
            }
            else
                *curr = n->branches[I].left;
        else
            if (n->branches[I].right)
                *curr = n->branches[I].right;
            else
                *curr = nullptr;
        remove_node<I + 1>(n);
    }

    template <>
    void remove_node<num_element>(node* n) {}

private:
    mem_pool<node> m_nodepool;
    node* m_roots[num_element];
};
```

`mem_pool` is my implementation of free list memory pool allocator for data locality and fast allocation.

This implementation is basically a one big graph where each element has a binary search tree structure. A node has an left/right child node for each of the element. The values of each entry are stored as a tuple in each node.

`emplace` function creates a node with a tuple constructed with given arguments, and calls `insert_node<0>` which will insert the newly created node in the binary tree structure of the first element, then call `insert_node<1>` for second element, and so on recursively until `insert_node<num_element>`. The container accepts duplicate entries, which will be placed as the left child of already existing entry.

`find<0>` searches by the first element(`int` in the example code's case), `find<1>` searches by the second element(`std::string` in the example code's case) and so on; returning `iterator<I>` that points to the found entry.

`erase` function takes said `iterator<I>` to removes the node it points to. 
The function does so by calling `remove_node<I>` recursively before destroying the node, which will, for each element:

1. find parent node.
2. if one child, replace self with said child from parent.
3. if two child, replace self with maximum value node from left branch (has to be maximum from left if duplicates are passed to the left, minimum from right if otherwise).

I gave the iterator an index template argument, so that it could iterate based on given `I`th element. But I might not implement that feature since I won't ever have to iterate in my use cases.

### Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "omni_map.h"

int main()
{
    util::omni_map<int, std::string> test_map;

    test_map.emplace(3, "three");
    test_map.emplace(2, "two");
    test_map.emplace(7, "seven");
    test_map.emplace(1, "one");
    test_map.emplace(6, "six");
    test_map.emplace(4, "four");
    test_map.emplace(5, "five");

    auto it0 = test_map.find<0>(4);
    auto it1 = test_map.find<1>("seven");
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*it0) << " " << std::get<1>(*it0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*it1) << " " << std::get<1>(*it1) << std::endl;

    test_map.emplace(25, "twenty-five");
    test_map.emplace(16, "sixteen");
    test_map.emplace(18, "eighteen");
    test_map.emplace(17, "seventeen");
    test_map.emplace(23, "twenty-three");
    test_map.emplace(21, "twenty_one");
    test_map.emplace(21, "twenty_one(1)");

    it0 = test_map.find<0>(25);
    std::cout << (it0 == test_map.end<0>() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    test_map.erase(it0);
    it0 = test_map.find<0>(25);
    std::cout << (it0 == test_map.end<0>() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

    it0 = test_map.find<0>(21);
    it1 = test_map.find<1>("sixteen");
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*it0) << " " << std::get<1>(*it0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*it1) << " " << std::get<1>(*it1) << std::endl;
}
```

Above test code outputs as follows:

```
4 four
7 seven
false
true
21 twenty_one
16 sixteen
```

I have published the solution to my GitHub [here](https://github.com/Wulfhart/omni_map) to show the entire code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Can you show a complete test program (with the needed `#include`s and the main function) and the command you use to compile the code?

Comment: `std::iterator` is deprecated, anyway you have no iterator there...

Comment: @L.F. I published my solution to github [here](https://github.com/Wulfhart/omni_reflection).

Comment: @JoonghoLee: Why your rolled out your own alignment functions? Doesn't standard  std::aligned_storage_t is enough for your purposes? Also, aligned_alloc and aligned_free is not used in alignment.h.

Comment: @nomanpouigt Dynamically allocating with new operator doesn't seem to align the data, and std::aligned_new is not supported in MSVC, so I am using a code I copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133912). No good reason as to why I am not using the already declared aligned_alloc and aligned_free in the aligned_ptr implementation. As you can see from the commented out block of code below, I was experimenting with the allocation method, then didn't bother to change back after I decided to go with the original method.

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost Multi-Index Container](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library?

Answer (score 3):

`struct branch` can have default and aggregate initialisation very simply:

```
struct branch {
    node* left = {};
    node* right = {};
};
```

`struct node` has forwarding-reference parameters, then forgets to forward them when constructing its `values` member.  We should use `std::forward` here:

```
    node(T&&... t) :
        values(std::forward<T>(t)...) {}
```

`omni_map` owns memory through raw pointers in `m_roots` yet doesn't have a destructor to free all these, nor any copy constructor or assignment operator, so looks very vulnerable to all the usual pointer-ownership problems.